# Print awk for empty row

Tags: bash, printing, awk, null

I have one problem. I am using this code in bash and awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {print "CHR\tSTART\tSTOP\tPOCET_READU\tGCcontent"}'
for z in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 

do 
export $z
for i in {0..249480000..60000}
    do
u=$i
let "u +=60000"
export $i 
export $u 

samtools view /home/filip/Desktop/AMrtin\ Hynek/highThan89MapQ.bam  chr$z:$i-$u | awk '{ n=length($10); print gsub(/[GCCgcs]/,"",$10)/n;}'| awk -v chr="chr"$z -v min=$i -v max=$u '{s+=$1}END{print chr,"\t",min,"\t",max,"\t",NR,"\t",s/NR}}'   
done 
done
```

From this I am getting the result like this:

> chr1  60000  120000  30  0.333
>
> chr3  540000 600000  10  0.555

The step of loop is 60000, but if I divide s/NR, sometimes the NR is 0 and this row is not in output. Thank I wan to get if the NR=0 and s/NR does not exist (because we cannot divide by 0):

> chr1 0  60000  N/A  N/A
>
> chr1 60000 120000 30 0.333
>
> chr3 480000 540000  N/A N/A
>
> chr3 540000 600000 10 0.555

I tried use condition like

`{s+=$1}END{print chr,"\t",min,"\t",max,"\t",NR,"\t",s/NR; if (S/NR == "") print chr,"\t",min,"\t",max,"\t","N/A","\t","N/A"}'`
But it doesnt work.
Could you help me please?

Comment: I receive at terminal this syntax : ./name_of_my_script.sh: line 20: export: `1380000': not a valid identifier

Comment: It should be `export z`, not `export $z`. But why do you need to export the variable at all? You don't have any subprocesses that access the environment variable.

Comment: If I dont export it from bash to awk, I cannot print it in awk. And if I change it, I get the same result without rows for NR == 0

Comment: When you use `-v min=$i`, the variable is being expanded by the shell, not by awk. So you don't need to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're dividing by zero, which is an error. You need to test `NR` before doing the division.

```
awk -v chr="chr"$z -v min=$i -v max=$u '
    {s+=$1}
    END {print chr, "\t", min, "\t", max, "\t", (NR ? NR : "N/A"), "\t", (NR ? s/NR : "N/A")}'
```

Comment: Oh really thank you, it works. And I try to delete all exports and it works too. Thank you for your help.